# Filtering pages by fields of child pages of the nested level in Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

There is the following page structure:
`ServiceCategoryPage` -> `ServicePage` -> `TariffPage`

and

```py
TariffPagePrices(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(TariffPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='tariff_prices')
    ....
```

How to filter the results of page `ServiceCategoryPage` on page `ServicePage` by the properties of model `TariffPagePrices`?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what query you are trying to write and what page you are on when writing it? 

I am guessing you are on `ServiceCategoryPage` and you want to show a list of ServicePages that have ??? something. Do you really want the tree relationship between ServicePage and TariffPage? And is TariffPage something visible as its own page?

Comment: @cnk Yes, I'm on ServiceCategoryPage and I want to show the ServicePage list. TariffPage is used as a page. But TariffPagePrices is not a visible page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.